# Delete all hidden rows using python

Tags: python, xlsx

There are some hidden rows in my xlsx file. I want to remove them using python. Is there any python solution? [image: Sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of **openpyxl** library in python.  The workbook loaded via this library has a hidden property available in the Row Dimension of the workbook (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/dimensions.html?highlight=hidden)

You can iterate over the rows and exclude rows which have hidden property set to true and create a new excel with the non-hidden rows.